# Getting "Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns" error with a regular expression

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kibana (
    `class` string,
    `log.file.path` string,
    `message` string,
    `requestid` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex' = "^(\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))T(([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\\d):([0-5]?\\d)):\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}.*(?<=ID:)(.*?)(?=\\s) \\|([^|]*)$")
LOCATION 's3://temp-athena-poc/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Error:

> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
>
> This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: d48ea089-02be-4884-a618-75b6a7af9dfe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' serde in ROW FORMAT SERDE, and removed 'input.regex'
Its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has more capture groups (sequences in parentheses) than the table has columns. Make sure your regex is correct and matches only the four columns you have specified. You can test your regex against data on https://regex101.com

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.kibana31(
  `requestId` string,
  `level` string,
  `time` date,
  `thread` string,
  `class` string,
  `line` string,
  `message` string )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex' = "[^\"]*(?=\" *(?:,|}))")
LOCATION 's3://temp-athena-poc" ;    What's the error now?